# Bind IIS to hostname (internal computer name)

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8

I first tried to bind IIS site to IP. While being successful at doing so, the internal organisation IPs are dynamic so the site went offline the next day. Non-dynamic are hostnames (computer names).

How can I achieve binding to hostname (my computer namer) so that the site will be reachable at the same URL containing hostname?

Comment: How many sites you want to host? The default is to bind to all unassigned IP addresses and should work for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose binding `*`, by default it is `All Unassigned`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do I then just put domain name which happens to be my copmuper name (PC6718228) as host name? Or where will my IIS site be accessible elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, how do you want to access the website?